# Not sure if programmer or ATMega is burned

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, arduino-uno, atmega

Some time ago i tried doing [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CMz2DYpos8w) with my original arduino uno r3. I guess i had to plug the power cables in wrong order(i think it's called reversing polarity) because my arduino stoped working. It turns on (the power diode is on) but i cannot upload any sketch on it. I'm thinking about changing the ATMega chip but, before i do that i want to be certain that it's the chip issue ,not the programmer. I have another arduino uno, and i heard that i can upload sketch with it to another uno. So my idea is, if i do this i will be able to say whether it's the programmer or the chip issue. The only problem is that i don't know how to do this and i wasn't able to find any reasonable tutorials online. Please tell me what to do.
 Many Thanks,
 Jan

Comment: This isn't a computer programming question, it's a hardware issue

Comment: Swap AT Mega between  your Arduinos and you will see what is wrong.

Comment: @Barmar i meant internal arduino programmer (i think this is what it's called)

Comment: @Michal Foksa Well that's an idea that would work, but generally i would like to avoid desoldering and soldering chips

Comment: I thought  you have UNO, where chip is removable: http://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/ArduinoUno_R3_Front.jpg . Then I cannot help.

Comment: Well it is , but first you have to desolder it at the bottom. But no worries i found an answer. Somebody answered me in another thread on Arduino Stack Exchange. Heres a [link](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/10420/not-sure-if-programmer-or-atmega-is-burned). Thanks a lot anyways :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Anyone with the same problem. Somebody answered my question on another Stack Exchange. It is [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/10420/not-sure-if-programmer-or-atmega-is-burned). Also [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=muP1dp73Mdg) video may be helpful. It sure was to me. Basically you need another arduino, then you need to upload a ArduinoISD sketch(which is built in Arduino IDE) to it, and connect the arduino you want to program to the working arduino(the one with uploaded Arduino ISP sketch) as in this [tutorial](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP) (there is something said there about the necessity of using a condesator i will update whether it is essential when i try it).